# Making buttons appear and disappear when clicked

Tags: swift

I'm playing around with `UIButton` and the `isHidden` property.  What I am trying to do is this:

- Start the app with `button1`.
- Click the `button1`.
- If `button2` is invisible, make it appear.
- Else, make it disappear.

If `button2` is pressed, make `button1` disappear or appear, depending on if it is visible.

When I click `button1` on startup, `button2` never appears.  Is there something required to refresh the view controller to show the new button available?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        button2.isHidden = true

    }

    @IBAction func clickButton1() {
        if button2.isHidden == true {
            button2.isHidden = false
        }
        else { button2.isHidden = true}
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton2() {
        if button1.isHidden == false {
            button1.isHidden = true
        }
        else {button1.isHidden = false}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set any `print(...)` statements inside the `IBActions`? Are they being reached?

Comment: Looks like you haven't connected the actions. Check that both of the actions are connected to the appropriate buttons. Also recommend you to updated the code to button2.isHidden.toggle() instead of everything in your actions

Comment: I actually connected these the other night when I was testing this out.  I just ran my code (with print statements added) and it worked as I expected.  Now I'm wondering if I just had an old simulator up before I connected the actions to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Check your outlets and .xib/storyboard. Maybe you just forgot to link view and with associated action.

Also you can simplifier methods.

Changes this

```
 if self.button1.isHidden == false {
    self.button1.isHidden = true
 }
 else {
    self.button1.isHidden = false
 }
```

to this

```
self.button1.isHidden = !self.button1.isHidden
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Btn2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        Btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Button1Pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        Btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Button2Pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        Btn2.isHidden = true

    }

    @objc func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button1Pressed")
        Btn2.isHidden.toggle()
    }
    @objc func Button2Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button2Pressed")
        Btn1.isHidden.toggle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Every change that you do on the UI, you have to execute it on the main thread, so you can try something like this....

```
@IBAction func clickButton1() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.button2.isHidden == true {
                self.button2.isHidden = false
            }
            else {
                self.button2.isHidden = true
            }

        }
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton2() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.button1.isHidden == false {
                self.button1.isHidden = true
            }
            else {
                self.button1.isHidden = false

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps you out....